# If a landlord donates commercial space to a non-profit entity, can the forgone lease value be deducted from landlord's taxes?

Tags: rental-property, tax-law, rent, non-profit, charity

I could not find a tax or IRS stack exchange so I post here.  Where I live, there is much commercial real estate that is empty.  I would like to propose to the landlords to donate the space to a non-profit temporarily until the market demand picks up.  Can I propose such a tax advantage to the landlord?  Does such a provision exist in the tax code?

Comment: Have you tried [Money.SE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No, there is no tax benefit to the landlord

Only gifts of property can be receipted by the charity -  not services or loans of property.

See http://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=7f940252-5177-4b48-82f3-c2db9dd7e5f4

Comment: Your link seems to concern Canada, but the question mentions the IRS, so it presumably concerns the United States.

Comment: @phoog I believe the rationale is the same everywhere - a donation must have a cost of some sort. The landlord is already claiming deductions for property costs and would have to pay tax on rental income - giving the space up freely has no impact on the landlord's income one way or the other.

Comment: We are in New Jersey, USA.  The article cited by Dale M is for Canadian tax code, but I assume Canada based their tax code on the IRS.